# x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (getting COM Port adresses) Python2.7

Tags: python, wmi

error: x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217406, 'OLE error 0x80041002', None, None)

I am trying to get the windows PC the detect the COM port of an Ardunio. The code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, when it doesn't i get the error listed above.

testing the code by plugging in and removing the Ardunio (giving ample time for windows to recognise it being removed). I tried searching for the error but nothing came up.

EDIT:
with some more searching i found its something to do with an Object Not Found Error. This happens when any of to COM ports change (when i plug in any USB device). The code can handle the list changing mid way though and so throws up this error. Im not sure how to handle the error in such a way hat it allows USB devices to change.

langpy:

```
    import os
    import time
    import ctypes
    import wmi
    import thread
    import pythoncom
    import locale

    def lang():
            localelang = locale.getdefaultlocale()
            language = str(localelang)[2:7]
            #print (language)
            return language

    def port():
                    while True:
                            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
                            Ardport = ""
                            c = wmi.WMI()
                            wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
                            for item in c.query(wql):
                                            s = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
                                            #print (item.Dependent.Caption)
                                            strfind = "Arduino"
                                            strignore = "bootloader"
                                            if (s.find(strfind) >= 0 and s.find(strignore) == -1):
                                                    Ardport = item.Dependent.Caption
                            time.sleep(1)
                            return Ardport
```

main code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import time
    import thread
    import os
    import serial
    import sys
    import ctypes
    import wmi
    from langpy import lang
    from langpy import port
    import pythoncom




    class service_test:
            def __init__(self):
                    thread.start_new(self.check_for_Ardunio, tuple())

            def check_for_Ardunio(self):
                    comp = ""
                    reply = ""
                    j1 = -1
                    while True:
                            plang = (str(lang()))
                            pport = (str(port()))
                            if (pport != ""):
                                    j1 = pport[-2:-1]
                                    comp = ('COM' + j1)
                                    if (reply == "reply" and j1 < 0):
                                            ser = serial.Serial(comp, 9600, timeout=1)
                                            if(ser.isOpen()):
                                                ser.write(lang)
                                                print ("sent message")
                            else:
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    reply = ""
                                    j1 = -1
                                    comp = 'COM'
                    #DEBUGGING
                            print(comp)
                            print(plang)
                            print(pport)
                            print (j1)
                            print (str(reply)) 
                            print ("")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            tst = service_test()
```

full error report:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method service_test.check_for_Ardunio of <__main__.service_test instance at 0x01FEE6C0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LeakDetectSys\Desktop\Keyboard\testing\application\test1wc.py", line 27, in check_for_Ardunio
    pport = (str(port()))
  File "C:\Users\LeakDetectSys\Desktop\Keyboard\testing\application\langpy.py", line 25, in port
    s = str(item.Dependent.Caption)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 555, in __getattr__
    return WMI (moniker=value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1290, in connect
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217406, 'OLE error 0x80041002', None, None)>
```

Comment: if ser.isOpen(): You can't write closed port

Comment: ok added if ser.open before ser.write however no change. The error is pointing me to langpy where i get the port of the Ardunio. s = str(item.Dependent.Caption) this generally happens when i unplug the Ardunio.

Comment: little more info. It
appears that an "OLE Error 0x80041002" is an "object not found error". so basically when i unplug the Ardunio it resets the com ports but the wmi code cant handle this. EDIT: This happenes when changing any USB device plugged in.

Comment: Freeze app(or missed / wrong driver). Plug in arduino and reboot pc.

Comment: Ardunio working fine, it happens if any USB device available on the COM ports change while its checking the list.